# Using FLVPlayback control - need to load policy file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

I simply need to play a video using the FLVPlayback control, but also need to generate BitmapData from it so I need to load a policy file but cannot find any way to do it!  It seems so simple, but it am going nowhere fast.

I have tried loading the policy file like this:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("PATH");
```

but that did nothing (although I can tell in the network events it is loading the file).  It still gives me a sandbox error when I try to access the BitmapData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by not using the FLV Playback control.